# Removing border on single list item

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to remove the separator next to one of the menu items as you can see in the screenshot below.

http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/9454/36513837.jpg

I can see in firebug that the separators are created using a border property. I'm able to remove the seperators from **all** menu items, but I can't see where and how to remove it from a single menu item. Is this possible?

[-> Website <-](http://tinyurl.com/cjy9lm3)

Comment: Just as a note, sound that you can't pause or turn off is bad website design.

Comment: haha, thank you Daedalus. I planned to fix that, something is covering the player controls at the moment. It's probably put off a lot of potential answers!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the :nth-child CSS3 pseudo class.

In your case, you could select the 5th child in the unordered list element by using `ul:nth-child(5)` selector and remove the border that way